# Loop through a list of items in a different order in each iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

So I have a loop and in each iteration, I want to go through the entire loop in a different order until the end conditions are satisfied.

During each iteration, the variables controlling the order in which I want to go through the loop change.

For example,

```
    while (endCondition == false){
        Item1;
        Item2;
        Item3;
    }
```

The first time I enter the loop, I want it to go through in the order 1,2,3. The second time: 2,1,3... and so on (Only I don't know the order for the n-th iteration before hand)

Is there a way to implement this at all? All suggestions welcome!

Edit: I know the order of the iteration at the end of the previous iteration. I want to know how to execute that permutation.

Item1, Item2, Item3 are functions that push elements into a stack. The loop runs until the endCondition element is pushed. At the end of each iteration, the top element is used as a reference to add 3 more elements, in the next iteration, using the above functions. I want to prioritize the elements pushed on to the stack to reach the endCondition faster.
And the order of priority will depend on how close the top element is to the endCondition.

```
    while(maze[currPos_y][currPos_x] != DESTINATION){

        int flag = 0;

        //Adding all open spaces around current position to stack
        if(maze[currPos_y + 1][currPos_x] == OPEN){
            path.push(currPos_y+1, currPos_x);
            flag++;
        }

        if(maze[currPos_y][currPos_x + 1] == OPEN){
            path.push(currPos_y, currPos_x + 1);
            flag++;
        }

        if(maze[currPos_y][currPos_x - 1] == OPEN){
            path.push(currPos_y,currPos_x - 1);
            flag++;
        }

        if(maze[currPos_y - 1][currPos_x] == OPEN){
            path.push(currPos_y - 1, currPos_x);
            flag++;
        }

        //If path is blocked
        if (flag <= 1){
            path.pop();
        }

        currPos_x = path.top_x();
        currPos_y = path.top_y();

}
```

`path` is a stack I implemented. There is no issue with the stack and it works fine.

As you can see, this code is going to run for a long time if the 2D array `maze` is large in size. So I want to make it faster by going in the direction of the `DESTINATION`. So the position that is closest to `DESTINATION` will be pushed last in order to be accessed first.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a random permutation of the n-items in the loop?  Or do you mean that you know what the order is going to be at the beginning of the iteration and just want to know how to execute the permutation?

Comment: @RobertPrévost I know what the order is going to be at beginning of each iteration and want to know how to execute the permutation. I shall edit the question

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you might want to look at [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: How are the permutations described?

Comment: @Yakk I have edited the question giving more details about what I wish to accomplish. Hope that helps

Comment: Could you please give an example of your algorithm? Sounds like you always want to use the last element on the stack first?

Comment: @MikeMB Yes. I have added the part of my original code in question to the post

Comment: Have you considered `A*`?

Comment: It looks like you should google "priority queue" and "manhattan distance".

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like a garden-variety `std::map` would be the appropriate container here.

Based on the information given in your question, it seems that you know what ordinal values are assigned to each instance of your object. You know which object is object #1, which one is object #2, which one is #3, and so on.

If so, then just put your objects into a

```
std::map<int, object_type> m;
```

Then, when you have an order of `[1,2,3]`, go ahead and do what you want with your objects, by accessing `m[1]`, `m[2]`, and then `m[3]`.

Then, if on the next iteration your order of visitation is `[3,1,2]`, go ahead and do your thing with `m[3]`, `m[1]`, and `m[2]`.

It might be slightly inconvenient if your class does not have a default constructor, and you can't use `operator[]`; if that's the case that'll be only a minor detail to square away, if needed.

Comment: Am I missing something or could an array/vector suffice here?

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. But what if my items are functions. How would I create a map then? I am new to C++. So this question might seem naïve.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the code below. Not knowing how you are getting the pattern back I have not solved for that part. This should give you at least another approach that's fairly conventional.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int subtractOne(int num){
    return num - 1;
}

vector<int> patternIteration(vector<int> pattern, vector<int> nums){
    vector<int> ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++){
        ret.push_back(subtractOne(nums.at(pattern.at(i))));
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<int> answer = patternIteration({2, 3, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 3, 8});

    for (int i = 0; i < answer.size(); i++){
        cout << answer.at(i) << " \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```